# How can i get all values of a particular key from object array without loop in angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

```
[{"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-03-08 05:46:01","type":"ar"},
]
```

here I want only ***type*** key all values

like that
Please help me to do so thanks in advance to all.

Comment: You can't do that without looping through the array. But if you are looking for some specific use-case, please add your use-case as well.

Comment: Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `myArray.map(item => item.type)`. Note that the array is still being implicitly looped.

Comment: you can use `map` method.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way would be to use `Array.map` method like so:

```
let array = [{"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-03-08 05:46:01","type":"ar"},
]

array = array.map(i => i.type);
// ["ae", "ar", ...]

array = array.map(i => {return { type: i.type }})
// [ {"type": "ae"}, {"type": "ar"}, ... ]
```